# Redirecting to 404 page when wrong url is entered

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I  have a 404 error page and tried the below code which was generated from this [link](https://www.aleydasolis.com/htaccess-redirects-generator/set-personalized-404-page/). But when the wrong URL is entered it redirects to the main page, not to the 404 error page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.rcis.in/404.php
</IfModule>
```

I have added the code in htaccess file.
And also how to remove the file extension from the URL. Down below is the code I tried

```
 #Remove extension
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

And I tried below code which was generated from that website which is mentioned above

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(php)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

How can I solve these two

Thank You in advance

Comment: Updated my latest answer

Answer (score 2):

The below code will remove php extention from the URL

```
RewriteEngine On
# for 404 redirection
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.yourdomain.in/404
# below code rewrites php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
# Remove php extention
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Hence the url https://www.yourdomain.in/404  will load https://www.yourdomain.in/404.php

Comment: the above code removes the `PHP` extension but it does not redirect to other pages

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: Currently, my URL for a page is https://www.yourdomain.in/page.php and I'm in a home page and I added the above which removes extension and if I try to redirect to that page then it is not going to that page

Comment: Still not clear for me Can you explain it briefly .. I am not clear about what you mean by`redirection` here